# Getting an error accessing Google Optimize Editor

Tags: google-optimize

I'm trying to access google optimize editor but I'm getting the following error:

```
This page uses security features that are incompatible with the Optimize editor.
```

I've tried some extensions for this like "Ignore X-Frame headers" and "Allow  x-frame headers".

Can anyone please suggest any other solutions?

Comment: Error message: This page uses security features that are incompatible with the Optimize editor.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off "Edit Mode" in the Optimize experiment page.